# Optimizing functions taking matrix arguments

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization

I'm looking for general information on how to optimize matrix valued functions, I have the following function I'm looking to maximize (or figure out if this is possible at all).

```
MaximizeFunction[W_, DataCoupled_] := 
  Module[{newDataCouple},
    (* Elementwise Multiplication on a list of 2 element vectors *)
    newDataCouple = Flatten[List[Dot[W, #] & /@ DataCoupled], 1];
    (* Take the first and second elements of each of the vectors in the previous list and 
      perform an independence test on them to obtain the p-value *)
    Return[
      IndependenceTest[Extract[#, 1] & /@ newDataCouple,Extract[#, 2] & /@ newDataCouple]]];
```

Input values are of the type:

```
DataCouple = {{.5, .8}, {.7, .9}, {.6, .9}, ... } 
W = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}
```

Could I then use `NMaximize` or `Maximize` to optimize this function?

Comment: What are the free variables? Are you trying to find the W such that this function is maximized? Are there any constraints on W?

Comment: If it's a matter of finding `W` such that this function is closest to 1, there are a whole family of solutions. You can define a function `tomax[w1_?NumberQ, w2_?NumberQ, w3_?NumberQ, w4_?NumberQ] := 
 MaximizeFunction[{{w1, w2}, {w3, w4}}, DataCouple]` and use `NMaximize` on this. However, plotting with any values of `w2`,`w3`,`w4` you will find that there will always be a value of `w1` which maximizes the function (to 1). (This is very inelegant coding but it should work).

Comment: No constraints on W, but I know that the output is invariant under scaling of W. One proposed solution to this is to constrain W such that WW*= 2x2 Identity. The number of elements in DataCouple are high (~120000), but I will try what you suggested.

Comment: Would you be happy with a single solution, or do you want the whole family? If you just want a single solution then it appears from this example to be an optimization problem in one variable.

Comment: Just a single solution would work.

Comment: This isn't a *matrix-valued* function. It's a function whose arguments are matrices, but the *value* the function returns is a scalar $p$-value.

Comment: My mistake, title has been changed.

Comment: `Return` is not needed here and you can also drop the `;`.  This is not just nitpicking: while in this particular example it does not make a difference if you use it or not, when used inside some functions, it will return from those functions and not from *your* function.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I believe you can replace: `Flatten[List[Dot[W, #] & /@ DataCoupled], 1]` with: `DataCoupled.W`

Answer (score 3):

(Edit, I've edited the following almost entirely from the original, but the idea remains the same)

From the comments it seems that a single solution will be enough. You want the input of the original function to be a numerical matrix. You can set up a test for this as follows:

```
matrixnumQ[exp_] := MatrixQ[exp, NumericQ]
```

Then defining your original function to test this on the input you can use the original function directly in `NMaximize`.

```
MaximizeFunction[W_?matrixnumQ, DataCoupled_] := Module[{newDataCouple},
newDataCouple = Flatten[List[Dot[W, #] & /@ DataCoupled], 1];
Return[IndependenceTest[Extract[#, 1] & /@ newDataCouple, 
 Extract[#, 2] & /@ newDataCouple]]];

DataCouple = {{.5, .8}, {.7, .9}, {.6, .9}, {.4, 0.8}}
NMaximize[MaximizeFunction[{{w1, 1}, {1, 1}}, DataCouple], {w1}]
```

This should give you an answer without any errors.

Comment: When I put in W_?NumberQ for the MaximizeFunction I receive the following error immediately: The function value MaximizeFunction[...] is not a number at {w1}=.0914636

Comment: @RyanWarnick I've edited the answer to take this into account. This should solve the problem, but I'm sure that there is a more elegant way to implement the test of whether the input is a number-valued matrix.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you're after.  I took the liberty of simplifying your `MaximizeFunction`, and in the process it became about twice as fast.  I also got rid of the initial capitals.  Best to avoid them, and avoid conflicting inadvertently with built-in functions.

In a comment you indicate that it might be sufficient to find the maximum over orthogonal matrices ($WW^* = I$).  Then it is easy to do, since `RotationMatrix[t]` gives half of them. The other half of the orthogonal matrices are given by any reflection times a rotation matrix, such as `{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}.RotationMatrix[t]`.  In all cases I tried, the p-value, as a function of `t` was the same for reflections as for rotations;  further, the period as a function of `t` was `π/2`.  (Perhaps one should check that.)  If so, we can just use rotations.

```
maximizeFunction[W_, DataCoupled_] := Module[{newDataCouple},
   newDataCouple = DataCoupled.Transpose[W];
   IndependenceTest[First /@ newDataCouple, Last /@ newDataCouple]];
obj[t_?NumericQ, couple_] := maximizeFunction[RotationMatrix[t], couple]
```

We'll make up a large, random data set.  It turns out there can be several local maxima, so using `FindMaximum` would probably give unreliable results.  Another problem is that it takes a long time to evaluate a single function call.  This makes using `NMaximize` take a *very* long time.

```
SeedRandom[1];
dc2 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {120000, 2}]
(Table[obj[t, dc2], {t, 0.1, 1., 0.1}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First) / 10
```

> ```
> 0.2092696
> ```

Plot the function to get a sense of where the maximum is.  (Plot from `0` to `2 Pi` to check the periodicity.)

```
plot = Plot[obj[t, dc2], {t, 0, \[Pi]/2}, MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

[image: One period of obj[t, dc2]]

We can get a rough approximation of the maximum from `plot`:

```
maxpt = Last@SortBy[Cases[plot, {_Real, _Real}, Infinity], Last]
```

> ```
> {0.897961, 0.993164}
> ```

Use the first coordinate as an initial point for `FindMaximum`.

```
t0 = maxpt[[1]];
({pvalue, tsol} = FindMaximum[obj[t, dc2], {t, t0, t0 + 1/100}]) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {7.493610, {1., {t -> 0.891873}}}
> ```

Since we got a p-value of `1`, we know it's the maximum.
Here is the optimal $W$:

```
RotationMatrix[t] /. tsol
```

> ```
> {{0.627955, -0.778249}, {0.778249, 0.627955}}
> ```

---

Here's a function that does the whole thing:

```
findMax[couple_] := Block[{plot, t0},
  plot = Plot[obj[t, couple], {t, 0, \[Pi]/2}, MaxRecursion -> 1];
  t0 = First @ Last @ SortBy[Cases[plot, {_Real, _Real}, Infinity], Last];
  FindMaximum[obj[t, couple], {t, t0, t0 + 1/100}]]

findMax[dc2] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {26.854463, {1., {t -> 0.891873}}}
> ```

---

If maximizing over rotation matrices is not sufficient, then you could do something similar with a different parametrization of the matrices.  It tends to get harder as the dimension of the input domain increases.

If you know a formula for the p-value of the `IndependenceTest`, you might be able to use that to speed things up.  (If there is a formula that can be differentiated, then `FindMaximum` can use Newton's method and so on.)