# How to apply multiple/complicated requirements for a pattern in a function input

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

In [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25628/optimizing-functions-taking-matrix-arguments/25631#25631) question. I suggested that to test whether the input of a function was a matrix of numbers one could create the following test:

```
matrixnumQ[exp_] := MatrixQ[exp, NumericQ]
```

and then define the function as:

```
myfunction[W_?matrixnumQ]:=W
```

This is simple enough in this case but is there a way to test patterns on inputs in a single line if the pattern test is more complex than that above. Something like:

```
myfunction[W_?MatrixQ[#,NumericQ]&]:=W
```

This clearly doesn't work but just to give you the idea of what I'm looking for

Comment: You'd better use `Condition` (`/;`)  taking e.g. `Det[W]` as a definition, e.g. `myfunction[W_ /; MatrixQ[W, NumericQ]] := Det[W]`. This question should be interesting: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/533/placement-of-condition-expressions

Comment: Thanks @Artes, I wrote an answer below using `/;` after finding it in another question. Your implementation is better though. If you want to write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: The last line in your post will work - you just need extra parentheses:  `myfunction[W_?(MatrixQ[#,NumericQ]&)]`. See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/why-doesnt-patterntest-work-with-composition/) for an explanation. If this was the main difficulty you had here, I'd consider this question a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @LeonidShifrin, I would consider that a duplicate and will flag it as such. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More straightforward approach would be this:

```
myfunction[W_ /; MatrixQ[W, NumericQ]]:= definition
```

e.g.

```
myfunction[ W_ /; MatrixQ[W, NumericQ]]:= Det[W]
```

an example:

```
myfunction[{{1, 3}, {-2, -3}}]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

if e.g. the input is not a matrix or doesn't satisfy the condition
then the function is unevaluated

```
myfunction[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]
```

> ```
>  myfunction[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]
> ```

I'd recommend this post [Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/533/placement-of-condition-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I figured it out from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/using-a-patterntest-versus-a-condition-for-pattern-matching) question. The answer seems to be:

```
myfunction[W_?MatrixQ /; Apply[And, NumericQ[#] & /@ Flatten[W]]] := W
```

Any other suggestions would be great to know.